# How to make Repository Methods Async?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following methods on a Entity Framework **6** generic Repository:

```
public void Add<T>(T entity) where T : class {
  _context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
} // Add

public void Add<T>(Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> criteria) where T : class {
  _context.Set<T>().AddRange(_context.Set<T>().Where(criteria));
} // Add

public IQueryable<T> Find<T>(Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> criteria) where T : class {
  return _context.Set<T>().Where(criteria);
} // Find
```

How can I make these methods async?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: Do you really need it? The first and the third method are so light that you really don't see any difference when running Asynchronously. Even the second one doesn't get executed to retrieve anything (Remember the **Differed Execution** nature of DBSet<T>.)

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819165.aspx, it shows all about querying and saving asynchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't think you should force your repository to be async. What you should do instead is to make async your business logic, that would eventually reference your repositories and access them as needed. Your data access shouldn't know anything about the way it will be used somewhere else.

Comment: In fact I have a dispatcher that sends queries which are handled by handlers. But if I make my handlers async don't I need to make my repository async since it uses EF6? I mean, what happens inside the handler shouldn't be async?